# Comic from 60's or 70's with a criminal whose mind is put in a war robot

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading a sci fi comic when I was young, early 70's, about a criminal whose sentence was having his mind transferred to a war like robot where he would die infinite deaths but his mind would just be transferred to another robot. In the end, he beats the system by allowing a tank to crush his head, rendering his brain in his human form severely mentally disabled.

I thought initially that this was included in the short stories of *StarStream*, but I've collected those and the story isn't among them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember anything about where you read this?  Was it a stand-alone work or part of an anthology like *2000 AD*?  Colour?  Black and white?

Comment: It was in color, and I believe it was part of a collection of short stories. It had to have been published very late 60's or early to mid 70's

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Bad Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Company_(comics))

Answer (score 5):

This story is called *Welcome Machine* in [Sgt. Rock Vol. 1 #316](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sgt._Rock_Vol_1_316) (May,  1978)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by specifying some relevant details from the issue in question, and, if you have the means to do so, uploading a relevant scan. [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) offers some tips on how to write a good story ID answer.